# Create query "sum" multiple columns in Nhibernate

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, nhibernate

Need to create a query with query Over (Nhibernate) C#, to add more than one column. Example in pure sql:

```
SELECT SUM(col1 + col2 + col3 + col4)
FROM tabela
```

First I made this way:

```
Table table = null;
Session.QueryOver<Table>(() => tabela)
       .Select(Projections.Sum<Table>(t => t.col1))
       .Select(Projections.Sum<Table>(t => t.col2))
       .Select(Projections.Sum<Table>(t => t.col3))
       .Select(Projections.Sum<Table>(t => t.col4))
```

But this way each column and generates 4 columns, would add all and generate a column only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simplier:

```
Table table = null;
Session.QueryOver<Table>(() => tabela)
       .Select(Projections.Sum<Table>(t => t.col1 + t.col2 + t.col3 + t.col4))
```

Comment: I like that, not to put more than one column. Displays exception:
Message = the variable 't' type Table 'is referenced in the scope' ', but it is not set.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius what type your cols? Can it be null?

Comment: I'm using decimal?, can be null. All of the same type.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius that's could be the problem. Just check it on null

Comment: I did not understand.

Comment: change `t => t.col1 + t.col2 + t.col3 + t.col4` to `t => t == null ? 0 : (t.col1 ?? 0 + t.col2 ?? 0 + t.col3 ?? 0 + t.col4 ?? 0)`

Comment: I made this way and are experiencing same problem.

Comment: I managed to solve the forum in Portuguese. Follow the link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138998/como-criar-somat%C3%B3rio-com-sum-com-multiplas-colunas-queryover/139117#139117